# Javascript/Rails - How to wrap link_to rather than <a></a> in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, link-to

I'm very new to rails and was using the jpages plugin for a concept. My javascript is as follows:

Javascript

```
$("ul#thumbs li").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
    var img = $(this).children().clone().addClass("animated fadeIn");
    var linkValue = $(this).children("img").attr("alt");
    $("div.img").html( img ).wrap($('<a></a>').attr('href', linkValue));
});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="thumbs" class="clearfix">
    <li><img src="example1.jpg" alt="page1.html"></li>
    <li><img src="example2.jpg" alt="page2.html"></li>
    <li><img src="example3.jpg" alt="page3.html"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to be able to change this line:

```
$("div.img").html( img ).wrap($('<a></a>').attr('href', linkValue));
```

so that the wrap would be something like:

```
$("div.img").html( img ).attr(linkValue));
```

with the html being:

```
<li>
    <img src="example1.jpg" alt="page1_path">
</li>
```

There must be an easier way than to take the alt info and wrap in javascript with `<%= link_to"` at the beginning and `do "%>` at the end. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, instead of creating, lets say `<a...><img .../></a>` you want to create `<%= link_to(<im .../>) %>` or something like that?

Comment: yes. basically <%= link_to(whatever the alt value equals) %>. any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't make sense, as $("div.img") is just a new element, not be linked to real dom tree.

Comment: That won't work. JavaScript runs in the browser, but the `<%= ... %>` are evaluated on the server side, **before** the HTML is sent to the browser. Unless this is actually for a client side template system or I'm still misunderstanding the question.

Comment: It is for a client side template system.

Comment: And which one are you using and how are you invoking it? And why is this question tagged with Ruby then if it has nothing to do with Ruby? You still cannot call a Ruby method from client side templates. Or is `link_to` a method provided by the template system? If you don't explain your problem properly we are not able to help you and we certainly don't want to ask for every bit of information.

Comment: I'm trying to include a rails link_to path in an html attribute to be rendered according to the javascript. I want the javascript to wrap the img alt attribute as a rail link_to. The reasoning for this is that it is a client sided template and I would like to be able not to hard code each link for numerous links. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong, but I thought this was a plausible idea.

Comment: It might be a food idea, but it's hard to understand your approach. As said, you cannot invoke any Ruby functions from JavaScript and it's sounds like that's what you are trying to do. It would be great if you could post an example of the output you are expecting. Or, going one step back, explain more about the *actual* problem you are trying to solve. Feel free to [edit] your question to provide more  information.

Comment: honestly, i'm sorry. i'm still trying to wrap my brain around ruby on rails. why i'm trying to put ruby into html when it renders ruby as html is me being dumb. to elaborate i was trying to have it so that when an img is clicked on, it renders a larger img of it above it like a gallery. however, i needed to be able to include a link with that larger img. rather than wrapping each larger img in a ruby tag, i was hoping to reduce the amount of coding by including it as an attribute in the small img tag and using javascript to wrap the larger img according to that attribute.

Comment: i was able to resolve it by just including the page link such as alt="page1" and leave the javascript the same (keeping in mind that my routes name paths are set accordingly). sorry for the lack of communication and confusion.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense now. FYI, you can use `data-*` attributes to store custom information on HTML elements. You don't have to reuse existing attributes for a different purpose. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes for more info.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible.

When you write `<%=` in ruby, if you have ever observed, HTML markup never contains ruby tags i.e. `<%=`.

Here, you are inserting ruby tags via javascript, but ruby tags cannot be written on HTML. They need to be compiled first.

Better you following or something like that.

```
$("ul#thumbs li").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
    var img = $(this).children().clone().addClass("animated fadeIn");
    var linkValue = $(this).children("img").attr("alt");
    $("div.img").html(img);
    $("div.img img").wrap($('<a></a>').attr('href', linkValue));
});
```

Comment: thanks for your post. this most basic concept helped me realize my stupidity haha.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby on Rails, end your javascript file with `.js.erb`

Now you can include Ruby in your javascript. e.g...

```
$("#container").append(<%= link_to "Foo", root_path %>);
```

If you need to access controllers or models (which I suspect you may need to), then calling ruby from your assets Javascript won't work.

You'll need to either write the javascript inline, as part of the HTML view, or create a javascript file that corresponds to a controller method, and call it from there. e.g.

In your Foo controller...

```
def some_method
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

In your Foo views, create a `some_method.js.erb` that contains all the javascript you need. The file will have access to your controller and model methods.